# Array Issues C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on [this](http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL/) problem. Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int numCases,num,zeroCount=0,mulFive,temp,i=0;
    cin>>numCases;
    //cout<<numeric_limits<int>::max()-1000000000;
    int solutionArray[numCases];
    temp=numCases;
    while(numCases--)
        {
            cin>>num;
            mulFive=5;
            while(num/mulFive!=0)
                {
                    zeroCount=zeroCount+ (num/mulFive);
                    mulFive=mulFive*5;
                }
            solutionArray[i]=zeroCount;
            i++;
            //cout<<zeroCount;
        }
    for(int k=0;k<temp;k++)
        cout<<solutionArray[k]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now when I simply output the result using the `cout<<zeroCount;` command which I have commented above I get the correct answers, but while adding the same solution to the array something happens and I get the wrong answers for some of the inputs. For the example given in the question link above here is my output.

```
6
3
60
100
1024
23456
8735373
0
14
38
291
6152
2189989
```

And here is the output when I input a single number.

```
1
8735373
2183837
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Is it too much to ask to know what you're *trying* to do?

Comment: @OllieFord It's supposed to calculate the number of trailing zeroes in the decimal representation of `N!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with arrays. The problem is that you're not resetting `zeroCount` between each case, so you're adding the result for each case to the result from the previous case.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    int numCases,num,zeroCount,mulFive,temp,i=0;
    cin>>numCases;
    //cout<<numeric_limits<int>::max()-1000000000;
    int solutionArray[numCases];
    temp=numCases;
    while(numCases--)
        {
            cin>>num;
            zeroCount = 0;
            mulFive=5;
            while(num/mulFive!=0)
                {
                    zeroCount=zeroCount+ (num/mulFive);
                    mulFive=mulFive*5;
                }
            solutionArray[i]=zeroCount;
            i++;
            //cout<<zeroCount;
        }
    for(int k=0;k<temp;k++) { // Always put bodies of if/while/for in braces, even if it's one statement
        cout<<solutionArray[k]<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't have much experience in competitive coding. So could you guide me on solving this problem more efficiently.

Comment: I have no idea what the best algorithm for this is. If you want people to critique your code and suggest improvements, try codereview.stackexchange.com.